# Most efficient way of building a menu out using a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following JavaScript array. Does anybody know of an efficient way of forming a multi-dimensional navigation menu without using a bunch of loops? I know the object could be more efficient but this is an example of how I'm receiving data from an API.

Array example:

```
var arr = [
  {
    name: "Mens > Jumpers > Cotton",
    id: 11
  },
  {
    name: "Mens > Jumpers",
    id: 12
  },
  {
    name: "Mens",
    id: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Womens",
    id: 14
  },
  {
    name: "Womens > Shoes",
    id: 15
  }
];
```

Desired output:

```
<ul>
  <li data-attr="13">Mens
    <ul>
      <li data-attr="12">Jumpers
        <ul>
          <li data-attr="11">Cotton</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-attr="14">Womens
    <ul>
      <li data-attr="15">Shoes</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Puzzle! I love puzzles!

Comment: I can modify the object before I run the output function. FYI! Just can't get my head around how this can be solved.

Comment: please explain the data structure.

Comment: split on ('>').. count that amount... the count is the level of the item... with the last one being the name, and the previous one, being its parent. (dont forget to remove 'white-spaces'. Store in another array with objects like `{id : ####, name : 'name', children: [childObjects]}`. Iterate over that array and make your structure

Comment: @PierreDuc, does not work with `"item two > item three"`.

Comment: This is the direction I have been leaning towards. How do I handle the order of the array being randomly structured? A potential problem would arise when the first item in the loop is 3 deep and I then have to create the children without an id and then reference it to come back and update it with said ID when I iterate over it. If that makes sense? @PierreDuc

Comment: @NinaScholz The last item in the string is the title of the category. That item then needs to be nested inside the previous titles mentioned in the same string. Each child also has an ID that needs to be associated with it's respected list item when outputted.

Comment: The array has a lot of redundant data. Anyway, will the data always be "logically correct"? For example a name: "item two > item one" would conflict with the others

Comment: @juvian I completely agree. I didn't design it, unfortunately! The data will always be logically correct. I don't think there is ever a case where the names would conflict each other. I used these as an example only.

Comment: I see. I still don´t completely understand the resolution of the id, for 1232 there is both item one and item two. But you use 1233 on the html

Comment: @juvian I can see how that is confusing. I've changed the code a little so that the question is clearer.

Comment: Do you mind using a dependency or do you want to attempt this from scratch?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm handling the data inside a Node Application so as close to Vanilla JS as possible. I'm really not keen on bringing something like jQuery in though.

Comment: Inside Node? Oh, that's perfect! Are you using Express?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I am indeed! Express and Handlebars, so a nice handlebars helper would be ideal :)

Comment: i would say the easiest method would be to iterate arr once, and along the way, you build the hierachies by splitting element.name by ">". Then you will have a hierachical structure that will map exactly to your expected DOM structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution using `Handlebars` as you requested:

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('nested',
`<ul>
{{#each children}}
<li data-attr="{{id}}">{{name}}
{{#if children}}
{{> nested}}
{{/if}}
</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>`);
```

To prepare the `arr` object to be the context of the partial:

```
arr = arr.map(function(li) {
  return {
    name: li.name.split(/\s*>\s*/g),
    id: li.id
  };
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.name.length - b.name.length || a.id - b.id;
});

arr = arr.map(function(parent) {
  var parentName = parent.name.join(' > ');

  parent.children = arr.filter(function(child) {
    return (
      child.name.slice(0, parent.name.length).join(' > ') === parentName &&
      child.name.length - parent.name.length === 1
    );
  });

  return parent;
}).filter(function(li) {
  var depth = li.name.length - 1;

  li.name = li.name[depth];

  return depth === 0;
});
```

The sorting above may be unnecessary, but I did it to be safe and ensure that parents come first, children come after. Below is a full demo:

```js
// initial data

var arr = [
  {
    name: "Mens > Jumpers > Cotton",
    id: 11
  },
  {
    name: "Mens > Jumpers",
    id: 12
  },
  {
    name: "Mens",
    id: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Womens",
    id: 14
  },
  {
    name: "Womens > Shoes",
    id: 15
  }
];

// Handlebars partial

Handlebars.registerPartial('nested',
`<ul>
{{#each children}}
<li data-attr="{{id}}">{{name}}
{{#if children}}
{{> nested}}
{{/if}}
</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>`);

// format data to context of partial

arr = arr.map(function(li) {
  return {
    name: li.name.split(/\s*>\s*/g),
    id: li.id
  };
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.name.length - b.name.length || a.id - b.id;
});

arr = arr.map(function(parent) {
  var parentName = parent.name.join(' > ');

  parent.children = arr.filter(function(child) {
    return (
      child.name.slice(0, parent.name.length).join(' > ') === parentName &&
      child.name.length - parent.name.length === 1
    );
  });
  
  return parent;
}).filter(function(li) {
  var depth = li.name.length - 1;

  li.name = li.name[depth];

  return depth === 0;
});

// render the HTML

var main = Handlebars.compile('{{> nested}}');
document.body.innerHTML = main({children: arr});
```

```css
body > ul {
  padding: 0;
}

ul, li {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

ul:before {
  content: "<ul>";
}

ul:after {
  content: "</ul>";
}

li:before {
  content: "<li data-attr=\"" attr(data-attr) "\">";
}

li:after {
  content: "</li>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, puzzles are fun :)

Here is my try : https://jsfiddle.net/pjuoxmpq/

```
var elems = {};
// place the items to object...
arr.forEach((item)=>{ 
  var path = item.name.split(">"), currElem = elems;
  path.forEach((p) => { 
    var pName = p.trim();
    if(!currElem[pName]) currElem[pName] = {};
    currElem = currElem[pName];
  });
  currElem._data = { 
    name : item.name.split(">").pop().trim(),
    id : item.id
  }
});

function get_elems( root ) {
  var str = "<ul>";
  Object.keys(root).forEach((key)=>{
    var data = root[key]._data;
    if(!data) return;
    str+="<li data-attr='"+data.id+"'>"+data.name;
    str+=get_elems( root[key] );
    str+="</li>";
  });
  str+="</ul>";
  return str;
}
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = get_elems( elems );
```

It could be prettier, using child objects might be nicer, but the `_data` works unless some category is named as "_data". Feel free to improve.

Comment: @AxelHunter Just to clarify, would you mind explaining why you changed your accepted answer?

Comment: I'd like to point out that this answer does not sanitize menu names and is vulnerable to HTML injection attacks should the API you're using be compromised. Handlebars sanitizes HTML internally, so you should stick to using your HTML templating service (Handlebars, Dust, EJS, etc.) when generating dynamic HTML.